# Remove some element from the list

Tags: c#, list, removeall

i m using C# 4.0.

i want to remove some element from my list.

i have a list A(type String) and List B(type T).

i want to take all element that in List A but not in list B --> i save it in Temp_Od_Scan (it works)

and all element that in List B but not in list A --> i save it in Temp_Od_Donne (it not works)

this code works fine (take all element that in List A but not in list B):

```
 bool Is_Egal = true;                 

                 foreach (string Od_Scan in Ordre_Scan)
                 {                    
                     foreach (Pers_Compare Od_Done in Outils.Get_Ordre_Donne())
                     {
                         if (Od_Scan == Od_Done.NoOrdre.ToString() && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Od_Done.NoOrdre))
                         {
                             Temp_Od_Scan_Egal.Add(Od_Scan);
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             Is_Egal = false;

                         }
                     }
                 }

                 Temp_Od_Scan = Ordre_Scan.Except(Temp_Od_Scan_Egal).ToList();
```

but this code not work (all element that in List B but not in list A), it not remove the element.

```
 foreach (Pers_Compare Od_Done in Outils.Get_Ordre_Donne())
             {
                 foreach (string Od_Scan in Ordre_Scan)
                 {
                     if (Od_Done.NoOrdre == Od_Scan)
                     {
                         Temp_Od_Donne_Egal.Add(Od_Done);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         Is_Egal = false;                        
                     }
                 }                    
             }

             Temp_Od_Donne = Outils.Get_Ordre_Donne().Except(Temp_Od_Donne_Egal).ToList();
```

and then i ask my friend google, and found another solution that not work also:

```
 Temp_Od_Donne = Outils.Get_Ordre_Donne();
                 foreach (Pers_Compare donneexist in Temp_Od_Donne_Egal) Temp_Od_Donne.Remove(donneexist);
```

or like this:

```
 Temp_Od_Donne.RemoveAll(i => Temp_Od_Donne_Egal.Contains(i));
```

or like this:

```
var list1 = Outils.Get_Ordre_Donne().Where(o => Ordre_Scan.Any(s => s != o.NoOrdre));
```

my class look like this:

```
 public class Pers_Compare 
    {
        string _NoLV;
        public string NoLV
        {
            get { return _NoLV; }
            set { _NoLV = value; }
        }

        string _NoOrdre;
        public string NoOrdre
        {
            get { return _NoOrdre; }
            set { _NoOrdre = value; }
        }

        public int CompareTo(string other)
        {
            return this.NoOrdre.CompareTo(other);
        }
    }
```

there are no error, i just not remove the element.
i have 345 element in A and 3 element in B.
1 element in A match 1 element in B
so the list Temp_Od_Donne return 2 (correct)
but the list Temp_Od_Donne return 345 (not correct, it should return 344)

but strange is about this loop:

```
 Temp_Od_Donne = Outils.Get_Ordre_Donne();
                 foreach (Pers_Compare donneexist in Temp_Od_Donne_Egal)
                 {
                     Temp_Od_Donne.Remove(donneexist);  
                 }
```

before it enter the loop Temp_Od_Donne.count = 345 and after it enter the loop Temp_Od_Donne.count = 345...strange...

Comment: Can you define `not work` please? Does the debugger throw an error?

Comment: I know this isn't the question, but you should probably reverse the test Od_Scan == Od_Done.NoOrdre.ToString() && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace - put the null or white space check first.

Comment: And, did you look at the Temp_XX_Egal lists? Do they contain what you expect?

Comment: yes in Temp_XX_Egal lists i have what i expected

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you out. 
I have used some linq queries to solve your problem.

```
List<string> Ordre_Scan = "aabb,eeff".Split(',').ToList();                       // input for test (guess the scancodes)
List<string> pers_Compare_ScanCodes = "aabb,ccdd,eeff".Split(',').ToList();      // input for test (existing class string values)

List<Pers_Compare> pers_Compare = (from scan_code in pers_Compare_ScanCodes select 
                                  new Pers_Compare { NoOrdre = scan_code }).ToList(); // straight to a list to match your problem


var resContains = from pers in pers_Compare
              where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pers.NoOrdre)
              &&
              Ordre_Scan.Contains(pers.NoOrdre.Trim())
              select pers;

var resNotContains = pers_Compare.Except(resContains.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure I completely understand the question, but if you have managed to put all the elements that are in List A but not in List B into a separate list, then surely you could just switch your List A parts for List B and it will produce the same result?

Switch all of List A - List B
Switch all of List B - List A
Switch all of Temp_Od_Scan - Temp_Od_Donne

```
 bool Is_Egal = true;                 

             foreach (Pers_Compare Od_Done in Outils.Get_Ordre_Donne())
             {                    
                 foreach (string Od_Scan in Ordre_Scan)
                 {
                     if (Od_Scan == Od_Done.NoOrdre.ToString() && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Od_Done.NoOrdre))
                     {
                         Temp_Od_Donne_Egal.Add(Od_Done);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         Is_Egal = false;

                     }
                 }
             }

             Temp_Od_Donne = Outils.Get_Ordre_Donne().Except(Temp_Od_Donne_Egal).ToList();
```

This may not be correct or even close to the answer, I am quite new to programming and just thought I might try and help out, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (Pers_Compare Od_Done in Outils.Get_Ordre_Donne())
         {
             foreach (string Od_Scan in Ordre_Scan)
             {
                 if (Od_Done.NoOrdre.ToString() == Od_Scan)
                 {
                     Temp_Od_Donne_Egal.Add(Od_Done);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     Is_Egal = false;                        
                 }
             }                    
         }

         Temp_Od_Donne = Outils.Get_Ordre_Donne().Except(Temp_Od_Donne_Egal).ToList();
```